# How to draw in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I would like to draw a resolver, but I am lost finding how to do it in `circuitikz`, any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (0,0) node[transformer] (T) {}
    (T.A1) node[anchor=east] {A1}
    (T.A2) node[anchor=east] {A2}
    (T.B1) to[L] (3,0) |- (T.B2)
    (T.B2) node[anchor=west] {B2}
    (T.base) node{K}
    ;\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

EDIT1:

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (0,0) node[transformer] (T) {}
    (T.A1) node[anchor=east] {A1}
    (T.A2) node[anchor=east] {A2}
    (T.B1) to[short] (2,0) 
    to [L, l=$Rotor$] (4, -2.0)
    to [short] (4,-2.1)
    to [short] (T.B2)
    (T.base) node{K}

    [short] (7,0)
    to [short] (5,0)
    to [L, l =$Cos$] (5,-2)
    to [short] (7,-2)

    [short] (2,-5)
    to [short] (2,-3)
    to [L, l =$Sin$] (4,-3)
    to [short] (4,-5)

    ;\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Comment: it would be very helpful, if you could provide some code with what you have achieved so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use all the tikz commands in circuitikz.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (0,0) node[transformer] (T) {}
    (T.A1) node[anchor=east] {A1}
    (T.A2) node[anchor=east] {A2}
    (T.B1) to[short] (2,0) 
    to [L, l=\textit{Rotor}] (4, -2.0)
    to [short] (4,-2.1)
    to [short] (T.B2)
    (T.base) node{K}

    [short] (7,0)
    to [short] (5,0)
    to [L, l =\parbox{3cm}{Stator\\ K Ref Cos $\theta$}] (5,-2)
    to [short] (7,-2)

    [short] (2,-5)
    to [short] (2,-3)
    to [L, l_=\parbox{1cm}{Stator\\ K Ref\\ Sin $\theta$}] (4,-3)
    to [short] (4,-5);
    \draw[dashed] (4.1,-2) -- ($(4.1,-2)!1.2!(2.1,0)$) 
      node[above,text width=2cm] {Rotor Shaft Angle ($\theta$)}
      (4.1,-2) -- (4.1,1);
    \draw[->] (4.1,1) arc[start angle=90, end angle=135, radius=3]
      node[midway,below right] {$\theta$};
    \draw[<-] (T.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[below,text width=3cm] {Used in brushless resolvers only};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you very much, I wish you to have a nice day and your family, too.